# Какое максимальное количество записей в БД Mysql

Tags: mysql

Я новичок в работе с базами данных. У меня есть таблица зарегистрированных пользователей на сайте (users), хотел бы узнать, какое количество пользователей в ней поместиться? В интернете конкретного ответа не нашел.

Comment: Зависит от настроек `MySQL`, архитектуры бд и Вашего железа. При желании несколько миллиардов... А так, волноваться не стоит. К примеру, `MySQL` используется *Facebook* и им хватает...

Comment: Если очень хочется конкретики то: 4294967295 если делаете по "гайдам" из интернета и оставляете стандартный размер ключа Int32 (Поля ID).
**А вообще как написано в комментарии выше**

Comment: Для InnoDB внутренний номер записи - 6 байт. Так что на этом движке - 280 триллионов записей на таблицу.

Comment: Зависит от СУБД MySql, Postgre, MS SQL.
В Mysql есть движки БД, от них тоже зависит

Answer (score 2):

MySQL имеет 2 движка - MyISAM и InnoDB:

- MyISAM - количество записей `2^32 =~ 4.2e+9`, но настройками максимальное количество записей можно увеличить до `2^64 =~ 1.8e+19`
- InnoDB - не имеет лимита по количеству записей, есть лимит на размер 1 таблицы - 64 терабайта